# Websocket API python for FTX

Tags: python-3.x, api, websocket

I am having issue getting connected to the websocket api for crypto exchange FTX. The following link is the doc which is not really clear to me as a beginner.
https://docs.ftx.com/?python#websocket-api

Below is the code I am using to try and get ticket data.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import json 
import hmac 
import time 
import websocket

socket = 'wss://ftx.com/ws/'

api_key = xxxx
secret_key = xxxx

def on_open(ws):
    print('connected')

    ts = int(time.time() * 1000)
    signa = hmac.new(secret_key.encode(), f'{ts}websocket_login'.encode(), 'sha256').hexdigest()
    auth = {'op': 'login', 'args': {'key': api_key,
                                'sign': signa, 
                                'time': ts}}
    ws.send(json.dumps(auth))
    data = {'op': 'subscribe', 'channel': 'ticker', 'market': 'BTC-PERP'}
    ws.send(json.dumps(data))

def on_close(ws):
    print('disconnected')
def on_message(ws,message):
    print('got message')
    json_msg = json.loads(message)
    print(json_msg)

def on_error(ws,error):
    print(error)

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(socket,on_open=on_open,on_close=on_close,on_message=on_message,on_error=on_error)

 ws.run_forever()
```

I just cannot connect to it. I an getting the following message:

*[WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond*

If someone can enlight me on how it should work.
Thank you

Comment: You're adding an api key and a secret key as variables however your request doesn't seem to follow the guidelines over at https://docs.ftx.com/?python#authentication

Comment: Not sure it uses the same signature with the rest API and the websocket. Looking at the example rest api is: `signature_payload = f'{ts}{prepared.method}{prepared.path_url}'.encode()
signature = hmac.new('YOUR_API_SECRET'.encode(), signature_payload, 'sha256').hexdigest()` and websocket is `hmac.new(self._api_secret.encode(),f'{ts}websocket_login'.encode(), 'sha256').hexdigest()`

Answer (score 0):

Of course you are using websocket now.
But I think it is a little difference.
Try this

https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/84813/websocket.WebSocketApp

Comment: Hi Gavril, thanks for the webpage but it doesnt really tell me what is wrong with my code above and getting to the bottom of it will help probably be better for me to understand websocket.